# Connecting cleardb to Heroku using php

Tags: php, heroku, cleardb

```
// create connection
$conn = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $db);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$conn->close();
```

I am trying to connect my php file with a cleardb database using the heroku platform.  My connection details and config are correct when I test using the sqlworkbench, but how do I know if my php is connected?

I've tried `echo "Connected successfully"`, but it doesn't appear.

And where is the composer.json file?

Website : https://best-app-ever-g52grp.herokuapp.com/

Comment: What does it say for "$conn->connect_error"?

Comment: Hi @marklark It doesnt say anything, it's just the page itself.

Comment: Does it actually say, "Connection failed: "?